# how can i store the values of listView in an ArrayList

Tags: android, kotlin

### this is my code but the result is that the last row appear multi time

````
var listViewOrd: ListView? = null
listViewOrd = findViewById(R.id.List_Ordonance_add)
    var medicamentOrdonance = MedicamentOrdonance()
    var listMedicamentOrdonance =ArrayList<MedicamentOrdonance>()


 for (pos in listViewOrd!!) {
                    var nameMedicamentList = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_medicament_list)
                    val test = nameMedicamentList.text.toString()
                    medicamentOrdonance.nameMedicament = test
                    listMedicamentOrdonance.add(medicamentOrdonance)
                }```
````

Comment: list can contain duplicate values, can you please print "nameMedicamentList" and check if it contains the duplicate value .

Comment: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{b291af5 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-34,41 #7f0a02df app:id/name_medicament_list}

Comment: this what i got when i print it

Comment: but when i debug i found it duplicated

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Collections are not supported, please use Lists instead

Answer (score 0):

list can contain duplicate values, can you please print "nameMedicamentList" and check if it contains the duplicate value .

you use the set data structure instead of array-list , it always contain unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` Can be used to make sure that you have only a unique list of items if that is your use case.

But if you are using `HashSet` for a custom object like in your case `MedicamentOrdonance` make sure to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` so that HashSet can figure out if the two
MedicamentOrdonance is really the same or different.

Then if you need the data in ArrayList you can do something like this `new ArrayList<MedicamentOrdonance>(hashSet);`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Your code just reads the contents of the same `TextView` over and over, and adds `medicamentOrdonance` (the same object) to the list every time, so you end up with the same thing lots of times.

If you're trying to read the contents of each list item, you should really just access the data that was used to create the list, that's being used in its `ListAdapter`. If you can't access that for some reason, you could do something like:

```
val adapter = listViewOrd.adapter
for (i in 0 until adapter.count) {
    val item = MedicamentOrdonance() // new one
    item.nameMedicament = adapter.getItem(i)
    listMedicamentOrdonance.add(item)
}
```

You need to create a new `MedicamentOrdonance` each time, otherwise you're just changing `nameMedicament` on the same one every time, and adding the same thing to the list over and over

Comment: but if i have many items in the row what i suppose to do to get them

Comment: A ``ListView`` displays a set of data. The thing that translates that data into "stuff for the ListView to display" is the ``ListAdapter``. So the adapter has access to the original data, and it tells the list view what to display for each row. We're calling ``adapter.getItem(i)`` up there to get the original data for a row, and we're doing it for every row. If the adapter's doing some conversion on the data for display, and you want that end result instead of the original data, you'll have to run that same conversion code on the data you collect - pull it out into a function or something